# What can it be an interpretation of the change of entropy in an equlibrium process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, equilibrium

I've been having some issues with this subject, and I'm pretty confused about the definition of entropy and specially concerning what could it mean when you consider the change on entropy from a system going from a state 1 to a state 2, and the meaning from the opposite, the system going from the same state 2 to an state 1. I've read that It could be related to the constriction grades of a system, but I would like to hear you opinions about this topic, any interpretation for this?

Comment: Your question is very vague. If the entropy change in going from state 1 to state 2 is positive then it is thermodynamically allowed for the system to spontaneously go from state 1 to state 2 and if the change in entropy is negative it isn't. What exactly are you after?

Comment: Just to echo the By Symmetry comment, have you a specific problem from a text book that you could include in your post. Thanks

Comment: It is as vague as it seems, the question goes like this: Give an interpretation of the change of entropy in an equilibrium process with respect of both directions in a certain process.

Comment: Or well I am satisfied with your definitions about entropy, because I dont get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that I am missing the point of your question. But here's my answer.

When a system is in equilibrium, the gibbs free energy is minimized. To say

$G=U-TS+PV$

P (pressure), may relate to the constriction you mention. However, as you see, T times the entropy S is a negative contribution to the free energy of your system. Thus, the larger the entropy, the lower the free energy (as T cannot be negative). So the system with the lowest free energy will have the largest entropy.

It is important to note that when your system is in equilibrium, no real 'process' (as in something that changes observables) is going on.

Imagine you have two equal blocks, and build a tower out of them. There are different ways of arranging the blocks that tower.

[image]

There is only 1 way to reach configuration 1 and configuration 2. So these have the lowest entropy (remember, $S = k \ln \Omega$), and the highest free energy. Configuration 2 has a higher entropy: you can build this structure in 2 possible ways. However, configuration 4 is the easiest to achieve, there are a lot of ways in which you can put both blocks levelled to the ground (you could even add intermediate levels with one block vertically and one horizontally aligned with the ground.

For the free energy, it should be noted that the internal energy of situation 3 is lower than that of situation 1, so its gibbs free energy will also be lower. As you see, the derivative of the free energy in these positions is 0 in all cases, which means they all are equilibrium positions. However, in the 'intermediate steps' (call it a process) this is not the case, so you cannot call these equilibrium. By going from one state to another, you can perform work on the system (change in internal energy) or the system can perform work. So that is how you go from one state to another.

To incorporate the PV term (is this what you mean by constriction grades?) you could imagine inflatable blocks or something like that...

Hope I did not make any mistake because of fast thinking/typing/drawing.

EDIT: regarding your comments, [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process) may be of interest. If there is a change in entropy during the transition from one state to another, the quasistatic/equilibrium process will be irreversible.